# Error while opening encoder stream in ffmpeg android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am trying to overlay a video on an image using the below command.

```
String[]sepCmd=new String[]{"-loop","1","-i",uri,"-i",overlayUri,"-filter_complex","[1:v]colorkey=0x000000:0.5:0.5[ckout];[0:v][ckout]overlay[out]","-map","[out]","-acodec","libfaac","-c:a", "copy",outputPath};
```

When I run the above command, I get the error as shown below

```
 Input #0, png_pipe, from '/storage/emulated/0/snowflake.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, gray(pc), 304x345 [SAR 11811:11811 DAR 304:345], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/FilterVideos/vintage1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
  Duration: 00:00:05.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 447 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 306 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (png) -> overlay:main
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> colorkey
  overlay -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0xee29d000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0xee2a8000] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to argb.
[libx264 @ 0xf125ba00] height not divisible by 2 (304x345)
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: @LordNeckbeard, I have tried those links but are not helping in my case

Comment: What did you try exactly? Add the scale, crop, and/or pad filter to make the height divisible by 2. See first link for the same situation as yours.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard is ffmpeg platform specific ? I have a command that runs successfully in Android but doesn't work with FFMPEG asset for unity

Comment: It is not platform specific, but that sounds like a different issue than what this particular question is trying to solve. I have seen your questions regarding ffmpeg on Unity, but I know nothing of Unity. It's probably a problem with quotes or escaping special characters.

Comment: Because right now I tried a command that is working perfectly with ffmpeg android sdk but doesn't work with ffmpeg unity sdk

Comment: I know. You already mentioned that.

Comment: `String[]sepCmd=new String[]{"-i",overlayUri,"-i",uri,"-filter_complex","[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[ua][b];[ua]setsar=1,format=yuva444p,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[u];[b][u]overlay",outputPath};`. See the command. When I run this in unity it says unable to find suitable output format. The only difference here is in Android I am testing in mobile and in unity on desktop

Comment: It is different from the one I mentioned in the question as after repeated trials I was able to make it work in android but not in unity

Comment: Is that not the [same issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1364448/error-while-opening-encoder-stream-in-ffmpeg-android)? This particular question on this page here is dealing with `height not divisible by 2`. Let's keep this discussion here limited to that issue.

Comment: Oh, you edited it so it is now a different issue as before and it is crossposted. Please do not ask the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites. It is discouraged as it dilutes effort, wastes time, and causes confusion (as shown here).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181566/discussion-between-vivek-mishra-and-lordneckbeard).